# When I click on an Microsoft Excel .xls file, it says "There was a problem sending the command to the program"

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-excel-2007

Odd error: if I click on an Excel 2007 file to open it from within explorer, it says "There was a problem sending a command to the program". Excel opens - but it doesn't open the file. I have to then manually open the original file using Excel's "File..Open" dialogue.

All of my other Office 2007 apps work fine, including Word, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem by upgrading to Excel 2010. Initially I tried the 64-bit version, however, when none of my prior plugins loaded, I switched back to the 32-bit version which worked perfectly. Office 2010 is much nicer - it loads way faster.

Answer (score 5):

In Excel's options (Orb -> Excel Options -> Advanced -> General) uncheck **Ignore other applications that use Dynamic Data Exchange**.  (I had this problem with Excel 2003; it didn't give the error message, but instead just opened the program without loading the spreadsheet.)

[MS Knowledge Base entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211494/en-us)

[Another page specifically mentioning this error and solution](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/jdavis/2010/02/01/excel-2007-there-was-problem-sending-command-program)

Comment: Thanks for the great hints - however, when I tried all of them (including unchecking the DDE option, installing SP2, etc), it didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @Gravitas Have you tried running Setup on the Office installation DVD, and picking the "Repair" option?  It's never helped for me, but maybe you'll be luckier.  :-)

Comment: Thx, I'll try that.

Comment: This solved the problem for me with Excel 2013 on Windows 8.1.